# How to set a different mobile for different instances of the same software application in app stores?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-development

I have been looking around on the internet for an answer to this question but have not found one. I want to create a mobile app that will be used across different groups of people. Because it is used across different groups of people I want to have a different mobile app icon and different title for the app relevant for each group of people however the actual app is the same. Therefore in the IOS/Android stores there would be multiple instances of the same software application however the title of the app and the mobile app image will all be different. I could theoretically have hundreds or thousands of the same application but with a different title and mobile app icon. These should exist in the IOS and Android stores. Is this possible to do? If so how? ... Any recommendations for documentation or tools to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Think of a different approach. Your current approach will result in your apps being rejected by Apple and you may even be removed from the developer program. See [spam](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#spam). You should aim for a single app instance with some other mechanism for people to join their group when they use it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I'd be curious as to _why_ you (think) you need this. If someone is in two (or more) groups, they'd need two (or more) identical apps? That seem silly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Paulw11. Apple has strict guidelines in order to prevent spam. You need a different approach... Have you thought about doing something dynamic within the app itself? like including the ability to change the app icon, colors and whatever else you deem fit? or as previously suggested implement a system where users can choose to be assigned to a specific group within the app?... once they select a group the app can adjust the branding, logo and features based on the configurations you set.

Comment: Yes I have thought of that. It is for customers who want their name as the app name and their logo as the app logo. It is as simple as that. I don't know how to put an app on app store that can have different names and logos but be the same app.

Comment: To do that the customer would need to publish the app under their App Store account.  The branding of the app needs to match the publisher of the app.  They could give you access to their App Store account for you to publish the app or you could provide them with the IPA to publish.